# ValueError: time data '19/06/18 10:40:01' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, datetime

My `chat.txt` file has text from whatsapp, formatted like so:

```
[19/06/18 10:40:01] She: ‎Messages to this chat and calls are now secured with end-to-end encryption.
....
```

And this is the code I'm using to parse it:

```
start = True

with open('chat.txt', "r") as infile, open("Output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        time = re.search(r'(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])', line)
        sender = re.search(r'(?<=\] )[^]]+(?=\:)', line)
        if sender and time:
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                time.group(),
                '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
            sender = sender.group()
            text = line.rsplit(r'].+: ', 1)[-1]
            new_line = str(date) + ',' + sender + ',' + text
            if not start: new_line = '\n' + new_line
            outfile.write(new_line)
        else:
            outfile.write(' ' + line)
        start = False
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
ValueError: time data '19/06/18 10:40:01' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

---

What am I missing?

Comment: %y instead %Y (%Y is 4 digit, %y is 2 digit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **y** instead of **Y** since **Y** will expect 2019 instead of 19

And make sure the 19 is the year or the day.  If it is 19th june, 2018 use this **'%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'**. If it is 18th june 2019 use this **'%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'**